# How to parse REST XML response to PHP array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, rest, response

I am building a webservice using REST. When client sends a request, server sends the response back as an XML string which looks like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xml>
      <item>
        <user>1</user>
         <name>cym</name>
       <house_number>23423423</house_number>
      <house_number_addition>sfsfsdf</house_number_addition>  
      <zipcode>erwer</zipcode>
      <city>werwer</city>
      <street>ertyu</street>
      <state_name>state1</state_name>
      <countryName>Albania</countryName>
      </item>
      </xml>
```

how can i parse the XML response as a php array like this?

```
     $arr['list']=array(name=>'abc',age=>'23',gender=>'male');
```

or

```
     $arr=array(name=>'abc',age=>'23',gender=>'male');
```

if this is not possible then how can i get the value of an attribute. I tried this using simplexml_load_string, but it returns null. this is my code for that

```
  $response= $ex->getResponse();
  $xmldat=simplexml_load_string($response);
  $i= $xmldat->name;
```

Comment: print $response and check if it is valid xml

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML allows you to interact with the XML as an object, but it requires that you specify each generation, starting with, but not including, the root element (in your case, `<xml/>`).

Try:

```
$i = $xmldat->list->name;
```

This will return an object of type SimpleXMLElement, but can easily be cast to a string if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that

convert it to array

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xmldat), 1);
echo $xml['item']['name']; // according to your XML, u should use `item` first then the element
```

OR

```
$response= $ex->getResponse();
$xmldat=simplexml_load_string($response);
$i= $xmldat->item->name;
```

Comment: i tried it manually on the given XML and it returns the value fine
..show the real full XML

Answer (score 0):

Few problem, XML is not validated. The following works, you should be able to build from there.

```
$xmldat = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<item>
<user>1</user>
<name>cym</name>
<house_number>23423423</house_number>
<house_number_addition>sfsfsdf</house_number_addition>  
<zipcode>erwer</zipcode>
<city>werwer</city>
<street>ertyu</street>
<state_name>state1</state_name>
<countryName>Albania</countryName>
</item>
</xml>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmldat);
print_r($xml);
echo $xml->item->name;
```